# TFS 2013: What's the best solution for needing additional states?

Tags: tfs, workflow, agile

I am using TFS 2013 MSF for Agile template. For a User Story, only following states are available, which are not enough for our teams:

1. New
2. Active
3. Removed
4. Resolved
5. Closed

I have a need to have the following additional states for User Stories and Bugs:

1. Ready for Development
2. In Development
3. Development Complete
4. Code Review Complete
5. Ready for QA
6. In QA
7. QA Complete
8. Ready for UAT
9. In UAT
10. UAT Complete
11. Ready for Deployment
12. Deployment Complete

How should I accomplish this? I am able to modify the workflow to add additional states and transitions. So, I know how to do that. But, is that the best solution? Is there better options to accomplish the same goal without adding so many additional states?

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Tanveer

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to manage this, or use a hybrid of both...

The first is to change the states and transitions of the work item. There is information on how to do that on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx).

The second way is to make use of the Kanban board. You can customize the User Story Board with the columns you need to visualize your team's flow (although you're looking at a lot of columns and that might not work too well).

Comment: So, it seems like adding all the described additional states will need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a good idea to enshrine your release pipeline within your work items. You would be better served using Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 to create a binary release pipeline and record the data of QA, UAT, and deployment within the release type there.

This tool is specifically designed for monitoring and managing your releases complete with approvals and validation.

You can find more information here: http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh. My question was more related to the project management aspect for having additional states. For example, if there is a Development team that needs to know how many user stories have analysis complete and "Ready for Development" that they can intake and start working. Same with all the other additional states I mentioned.